# Git Shell icon on WIndows 7 corrupt after update

Tags: windows-7, github

After an update of GitHub for Windows, the icon for "Git Shell" has got corrupt - it shows an icon for an "unknown file".

The shortcut points to `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell`.

Is there any way to recover it? Please let know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following from the GitHub Git shell:

```
github --reinstall-shortcuts
```

If the Git Shell icon doesn't work, you can start the shell from inside GitHub for Windows. In the current version, 2.2.0.0 it's found under the settings menu (looks like a gear).

Comment: From the regular command prompt?